Neighbourhood basis made of balls
I'm studying general topology and a question has come to my mind.
By definition, in a topological space, a neighbourhood basis of a point x is a subset of its neighbourhoods such that every neighbourhood of x contains one element of that subset, where a subset is neighbourhood of x if it contains an open set containing x. Furthermore, in a metric space, given a point x and a real number r>0, the ball of radius r centred in x is defined as the set of points at distance strictly less than r from x.
It is known that in a metric space (topologised in the standard way induced by the metric), fixing a point x, the set of balls of arbitrary radii centred in x is a neighbourhood basis of the point. My question is the following: given a subset S of positive real numbers, on which conditions is the set of balls centred in x with radii in S a neighbourhood basis of x?
By now I've only come up with a somewhat ugly condition, distinguishing depending on the fact that there exist points at arbitrary small distances from x (in that case, it seems to be necessary and sufficient for S of having infimum equal to 0) and otherwise (in that case, calling m the positive infimum of those distances, S should intersect $(0,m]$). Does anyone have a better insight?

Define "better insight". Your condition on $S$ having elements arbitrarily small is correct. And I don't see anything "ugly" about it.

@freakish A ‘better’ condition (as in the bold question) in my view would be a condition on S treating in equal way every x, not distinguishing between points having or not having points at arbitrary small distances.

The only condition you need is that for any $r>0$ there is $s\in S$ such that $0<s<r$. That's all. It doesn't depend on $x$. It doesn't matter whether $x$ is isolated or not, the condition works for both cases.

@freakish I can see that. The point is that neither of the two conditions for the two separate cases is necessary and sufficient in the other case.

Condition $\inf S=0$ is sufficient but not always necessary. For instance take the case where the metric only takes values in ${0,1}$ (corresponding with discrete topology). Then e.g. $\inf S<1$ also works.

@drhab You’re right, that is the exact case that made me find the longer condition.

The condition $inf S=0$ is necessary with respect to all metric spaces. In some special cases, it is not necessary. But then the question is no longer about arbitrary metric space, but about a concrete metric space. Or a class of spaces. So what kind of metric spaces you want?

@freakish Let’s put it this way. Consider a metric space X and a point x in it. Then a set S of positive real numbers is such that the set of balls centred in x and with radii in S is a neighborhood basis for x if and only if P(X, x, S). Find P syntactically not presenting subcases (e.g. if… then…, else if…, then…).

Something along the lines of $P(X,x,S)=\forall y\in X\exists s\in S(s<d(x,y))$? It’s not so clear what you’re accepting as a “valid” property

@AlessandroCodenotti Yes, that would be valid. I did not imply necessarily writing P symbolically, I used that notation only to emphasise the possible dependences along with the fact that, for every X, x and S, P should be able to characterise all  and only the S’s having that property with respect to X and x. If  this all can be said better using logic notions, please make a note of, in order to help the next answerers.

@AlessandroCodenotti Valid but not true, just to say.

Why not? @AmandaWealth

@AlessandroCodenotti Since d(x,x) = 0 your condition would require S to contain a positive number less than 0, which is clearly unsatisfiable. Futhermore, even excluding y = x from the universal quantifier would not lead to a necessary condition for all cases: e.g., in a discrete metric space with two points (with d(x,y) = 1 if and only if x is different from y), that would require S to hold a number less than 1, and still S = {1} would be an admissible set.

Fair enough, change it to include $y\neq x$ and $\exists s\in S(s\leq d(x,y))$ then

@AlessandroCodenotti Consider the subset S = {1 + 1/n} for n positive natural number, X to be the union of S and {0} endowed with the metric induced by the Euclidean metric of R, taking 0 as x. Your condition P(X,x,S) it is valid for the above choices, but the set of balls with radii in S is not a neighbourhood basis for 0 (every ball with radius in S contains a point other than 0 and therefore none of them is contained in the ball with radius 1, which is equal to {0}).

The question is easy.
Let $(X,d)$ be any metric space consisting of at least two points and $x\in X$ be any point. For any real $r$ let $B_r=\{y\in X: d(y,x)<r \}$. For any set $S$ of positive real numbers put $\mathcal B_S=\{B_r:r\in S\}$.
Put $D=\inf\{d(y,x):y\in X\setminus\{x\}\}$. The following cases are possible.
1)) There exists $y\in X\setminus \{x\}$ such that $d(x,y)=D$. Then it is easy to check that $\mathcal B_S$ is a base at $x$ iff there exists $r\in S$ such that $s\le D$. Then $B_r(x)=\{x\}$.
2)) For each $y\in X\setminus \{x\}$ we have $d(x,y)>D$. Then it is easy to check that $\mathcal B_S$ is a base at $x$ iff $\inf S\le D$.

Your condition is true but not substantially new with respect to what previously said, and furthermore it lacks the conciseness I was looking for (adding the further constraint on the space having more than one point). Thank you anyway, I start to think there's no shorter way to express it.

That condition is not sufficient, as I’ve already pointed out in a previous comment.

"Consider the subset S = {1 + 1/n} for n positive natural number, X to be the union of S and {0} endowed with the metric induced by the Euclidean metric of R, taking 0 as x. Your condition P(X,x,S) it is valid for the above choices, but the set of balls with radii in S is not a neighbourhood basis for 0 (every ball with radius in S contains a point other than 0 and therefore none of them is contained in the ball with radius 1, which is equal to {0})".
